How to get Docker Container statistics using API?
I'm developing a container monitoring system, and it's important for me to know some data that is not returned when using containers/{id}/stats

I would like to get network I/O data, unfortunately I can’t get it using stats, although Docker Desktop has it
The same thing with Disk read/write, it is in Docker Desktop, but not in the official api/stats
I would like to know how much maximum space on a hard drive a container can occupy, as well as how much it currently occupies, I know that there is SizeRw and SizeRootFs, but this is not very convenient and it only shows how much the container occupies, and does not show how much maximum a container can occupy

P.s. If anything, the service is developed in Java

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
